# Salesforce Outlook - Case

Tags: customization, salesforce-for-outlook, connect-for-outlook, dreamforce

I had installed the SF for Outlook.

My requirement is that :

1) Need to create the CASE from the Outlook

2) Once a case is created from the Outlook and we want to update something (via reply to the same email (using Same THREAD Id)) the data should update in the same Case no.

3) From the CUSTOMER pros, if any customer will send an email to "support@abc.com", automatically case will create and Case no will assign to CUSTOMER.

4) If customer will reply on the same email or any email which was received by Support user with the "THREAD ID" the data should be updated into the same Case no.

Comment: I think, what you're talking about is "Email to Case" and should be pretty easy to accomplish following the standard setup found here https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customizesupport_email.htm

Comment: @HomerJ -  I am facing some issue: Once Case will create from the Outlook and if any of the Support users will reply on the same case no (Including - THREAD ID), that update will not mapped in the existing case.